# Cannot open file in write mode after copyfile

Tags: python, readlines

I am required to edit the file that's just created using `copyFile()`.

However, `readlines()` always fails if the file is opened in either `'w'` mode or `'w+'` or in `'a'` mode.

```
copyfile(fileObj.file_to_open, fileObj._copyToFileName)
    with open(fileObj._copyToFileName, 'w') as thisFile:
        lines = thisFile.readlines()
```

I am able to `readlines()` if I leave it to default mode (read mode).

Why would the open with write mode be a problem?

Comment: You are opening the file as ```write mode``` you need to open it as ```read mode``` , that means: ```with open(fileObj._copyToFileName, 'r') as thisFile:```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `r+` or `a+` mode, which allows read and write operations to files ([see more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466000/python-open-built-in-function-difference-between-modes-a-a-w-w-and-r)).

With `r+`, the position is initially at the beginning, but reading it once will push it towards the end, allowing you to append. With `a+`, the position is initially at the end.

With `f.seek(0)` you can move the reading position to the beginning.

```
with open("filename", "r+") as f:
    text = f.read()    
    f.seek(0)
    # reread if required here
```

Answer (score 0):

When you open a file in write mode, Python truncates the file. If you want to open the file for reading/writing without this, you need to use `open(filename, 'r+')`.

Also make sure that you keep track of where in the file the cursor is located because you may overwrite your data. Use `file.seek(offset)` to control this.

Check [the Python `open` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) for more details.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But I cant edit / write to the file if i opened it with r+ mode